# Collision detection problems - Javascript/Canvas game

Tags: javascript, tiles, maps, html-canvas

**What I want to do:**

I simply want the have a 2D array to represent my game map.

I want a player sprite and I want that sprite to be able to move around my map freely using the keyboard and also have collisions with certain tiles of my map array.

I want to use very large maps so I need a viewport.

**What I have:**

I have a loop to load the tile images into an array:

```
//Loop to load tile images into an array
var mapTiles = [];

for (x = 0; x <= 256; x++) {
    var imageObj = new Image(); // new instance for each image
    imageObj.src = "images/prototype/"+x+".jpg";
    mapTiles.push(imageObj);
}
```

I have a 2D array for my game map:

```
//Array to hold map data
var board =   [
    [1,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,5,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [17,18,19,20,19,20,19,20,21,22,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [33,34,35,36,35,36,35,36,37,38,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [49,50,51,52,51,52,51,52,53,54,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,197,198,199,1,1,1,1],
    [65,66,67,68,146,147,67,68,69,70,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,216,217,1,1,1,213,214,215,1,1,1,1],
    [81,82,83,161,162,163,164,84,85,86,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,232,233,1,1,1,229,230,231,1,1,1,1],
    [97,98,99,177,178,179,180,100,101,102,1,1,1,1,59,1,1,1,248,249,1,1,1,245,246,247,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,238,1,1,1,1,239,240,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [216,217,254,1,1,1,1,255,256,1,204,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [232,233,1,1,1,117,118,1,1,1,220,1,1,119,120,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,119,120,1,1],
    [248,249,1,1,1,133,134,1,1,1,1,1,1,135,136,1,1,1,1,1,1,59,1,1,1,1,135,136,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,216,217,1,1,1,1,1,1,60,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,232,233,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,204,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,248,249,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,220,1,1,1,1,1,1,216,217,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,149,150,151,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,232,233,1,1,1],
    [12,12,12,12,12,12,12,13,1,1,1,1,165,166,167,1,1,1,1,1,1,119,120,1,1,248,249,1,1,1],
    [28,28,28,28,28,28,28,29,1,1,1,1,181,182,183,1,1,1,1,1,1,135,136,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [44,44,44,44,44,15,28,29,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,27,28,29,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,27,28,29,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,59,1,1,197,198,199,1,1,1,1,119,120,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,27,28,29,1,1,216,217,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,213,214,215,1,1,1,1,135,136,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,27,28,29,1,1,232,233,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,229,230,231,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,27,28,29,1,1,248,249,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,245,246,247,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,197,198,199,28,29,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,213,214,215,28,29,1,1,1,1,1,60,1,1,1,1,204,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,229,230,231,28,29,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,220,1,1,1,1,119,120,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,245,246,247,28,29,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,135,136,1,1,60,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,27,28,29,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,27,28,29,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
];
```

I have my loop to place the correct tile sin the correct positions:

```
//Loop to place tiles onto screen in correct position
for (x = 0; x <= viewWidth; x++){
    for (y = 0; y <= viewHeight; y++){
        var width = 32;
        var height = 32;
        context.drawImage(mapTiles[board[y+viewY][x+viewX]],x*width, y*height);
    }
}
```

I have my player object :

```
//Place player object
    context.drawImage(playerImg, (playerX-viewX)*32,(playerY-viewY)*32, 32, 32);
```

I have my viewport setup:

```
//Set viewport pos
viewX = playerX - Math.floor(0.5 * viewWidth);
    if (viewX < 0) viewX = 0;
    if (viewX+viewWidth > worldWidth) viewX = worldWidth - viewWidth;


    viewY = playerY - Math.floor(0.5 * viewHeight);
    if (viewY < 0) viewY = 0;
    if (viewY+viewHeight > worldHeight) viewY = worldHeight - viewHeight;
```

I have my player movement:

```
canvas.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    var key = null;
    switch (e.which) {
        case 37:
            // Left
            if (playerY > 0) playerY--;
            break;
        case 38:
            // Up
            if (playerX > 0) playerX--;
            break;
        case 39:
            // Right
            if (playerY < worldWidth) playerY++;
            break;
        case 40:
            // Down
            if (playerX < worldHeight) playerX++;
            break;
    }
```

**My Problem:**

I have my map loading an it looks fine, but my player position thinks it's on a different tile to what it actually is.

So for instance, I know that if my player moves left 1 tile, the value of that tile should be 2, but if i print out the value it should be moving to (2), it comes up with a different value.

**How I've tried to solve the problem:**

I have tried swap X and Y values for the initialization of my player, for when my map prints.

If I swap the X and Y values in this part of my code:

```
context.drawImage(mapTiles[board[y+viewY][x+viewX]],x*width, y*height);
```

The map doesnt get draw correctly at all and tiles are placed all in random positions or orientations

If I swap the X and Y values for my player in this line :

```
context.drawImage(playerImg, (playerX-viewX)*32,(playerY-viewY)*32, 32, 32);
```

The players movements are inversed, so up and down keys move my player left and right viceversa.

**My question:**

Where am I going wrong in my code, and how do I solve it so I have my map looking like it should and my player moving as it should as well as my player returning the correct tileID it is standing on or moving too.

**ALSO**

Here is a link to my whole code:

[prototype](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2d19)

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: Where am i going wrong with my player movement or map?

Comment: These are the problems I'm having reading your question: You've posted a lot of messy code with no comments. I don't know what you want your code to do. I don't know how you've tried to solve the problem. These make it very difficult for me to answer.

Comment: ok ill post these details

Comment: Please look at my response below Anko, Thankyou very much

Comment: So i meant above

Comment: Where in your code do you query the tileId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code....

```
switch (e.which) {
        case 37:
            // Left
            if (playerY > 0) playerY--;
            break;
        case 38:
            // Up
            if (playerX > 0) playerX--;
            break;
        case 39:
            // Right
            if (playerY < worldWidth) playerY++;
            break;
        case 40:
            // Down
            if (playerX < worldHeight) playerX++;
            break;
    }
```

Should be:

```
     switch (e.which) {
        case 37:
            // Left
            if (playerX > 0) playerX--;
            break;
        case 38:
            // Up
            if (playerY > 0) playerY--;
            break;
        case 39:
            // Right
            if (playerX < worldWidth) playerX++;
            break;
        case 40:
            // Down
            if (playerY < worldHeight) playerY++;
            break;
    }
```

You got Up and Down mixed up with Left and right (And I'm assuming your comment are correct here), also worldHeight and worldWidth have been corrected.

I see no code that enquires what tile the player is currently under so unable to fix anything related to that part of the question.

The following should work:

```
 function getPlayerTile(x, y) {
     return board[y][x];
 }

 console.log(getPlayerTile(playerX, playerY));
```

Comment: Thankyou very much it seems to be working fine now!